# Aligning an Array List with multiple types with respective headers

Tags: java, arraylist, printf, tostring

I'm printing out an array list with multiple parameters under each header, via a toString method in a seperate class but I'm not sure how to format it so that it's aligned. What's a good way to implement printf in this situation? It seems rea

EmployeeFX(Where the toString method is):

```
package p20;

public class EmployeeFX
{

private static int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private boolean salaried;
private double salary;

public EmployeeFX(int id, String firstName, String lastName,boolean salaried, int salary)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    this.salaried=salaried;
    this.salary=salary;
}

public  int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public boolean isSalaried() {
    return salaried;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public final String toString()
{
    String str;
    str=String.format("%-3d %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3d", getId(),getFirstName(),getLastName(), isSalaried(), getSalary());
    return str;
}

}
```

EmployeeOrderingDemo(Where the output will happen)
    package p20;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class EmployeeOrderingDemo {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input=null;
    ArrayList<EmployeeFX> employeeList=new ArrayList<EmployeeFX>();
    try
    {
        FileReader Info=new FileReader("P01_DATA.txt");
        input=new Scanner(Info).useDelimiter("\\s+");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException noFile)
    {
        System.out.println("Can't open file");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    input.nextLine();
    input.nextLine();
    try
    {
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            employeeList.add(new EmployeeFX(input.nextInt(),input.next(),input.next(), input.nextBoolean(), input.nextInt()));

        }
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException element)
    {
        System.err.println("Wrong type of file");
        element.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException state)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't read from file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if(input!=null)
    {
        input.close();
    }

    outputData("Output in ORIGINAL order", employeeList, EmployeeOrdering.SALARIED);



}

public static void outputData(String str, ArrayList<EmployeeFX> employeeList, Comparator<EmployeeFX> specificComparator)
{
    String headerString=  "Id   FirstName   LastName    Salaried    Salary";//The headers themselves
    System.out.println("\n" + str + "\n\n" + headerString + "\n");
    Collections.sort(employeeList, specificComparator);
    for(EmployeeFX element:employeeList)
    {
        System.out.println(element);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: align the arraylist?can you be more specific what is the output you r loooking for?

Comment: Sorry. I have a series of array lists. Each array list has four data types. I wanna put those data types under the respective headers (It's commented in the second program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.format for toString to return a formatted string. Format it in the same way as if you were using printf.

-EDIT- Try %s for strings. Also, maybe %f for double. The number of digits past decimal place is also adjustable. e.g. If you only want two digits past decimal place, for example, you could say %-3.2f

Let me know if this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: One unrelated thing to note is your use of static int for id. All the objects will share the same id when you print this, unless there is something in your code that you're not including here. Static might be useful, for example, if you wanted to automatically increment the employee id each time you create a new Employee object. If you don't want all your objects to share the same id, I would suggest you don't use static unless you're planning on storing it into a non-static variable.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I got an IllegalFormatConversionException

Comment: could you show what you tried to do? (probably best to include in question itself)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was able to get everything neatly aligned. I also appreciate you pointing out that id was static. I was wondering why that wasn't being sorted